# Tipler cyllinder shouldn't have to be infinitely long

Tags: general-relativity, time-travel

Since information can only travel at the speed of light, the information that the cylinder is infinitely long will never arrive to any point of the cylinder. And if the information that its infinite has to arrive to all of the cylinder for it to work, it can never work even if it is infinitely long, yet it is still a valid exact solution in general relativity. Did I just discover an inconsistency in GR?

Answer (score 3):

The Tipler cylinder is also a static solution, meaning that it has existed for an infinite amount of time, hence any such information about infinity has the time to arrive.